# Is this QSort unsafe?

Tags: c++, crash, access-violation, qsort

I'm investigating a crash in our program. I'm looking at a QSort written by another programmer. I would like to discuss why this is unsafe with them but they have a better technical understanding of C++ than I do and would like as much information as possible. I can't paste the actual code but I'll do my best to re-create the essentials.

I can think of a few reasons why this is unsafe but would like more concrete talking points.

The QSort is run on two arrays with different structs who's first element is another struct called MyString. Otherwise the other elements of the struct are different. For example:

```
struct SItemA
{
    MyString ItemId;
    INT IntFoo;
}

struct SItemB
{
    MyString ItemId;
    FLOAT FloatFoo;
}
```

This is a performance critical app, so STL strings/arrays are not used. I'm not aware of the particulars of how strings/arrays are implemented but they're reliable and well tested by a larger community and are not the focus of my suspicion.

```
static int
IDCompare(
    void const* inA,
    void const* inB)
{
    MyString const* a = (MyString const*)inA;
    MyString const* b = (MyString const*)inB;

    return MyStrCmp(**a, **b);
}

appQsort(aItems.GetData(), aItems.Num(), sizeof(SItemA), IDCompare);
appQsort(bItems.GetData(), bItems.Num(), sizeof(SItemB), IDCompare);
```

QSort naively assumes that the address of the struct is the same as the address of the MyString element. As far as I know, this is true (for now) since C++ compilers guarantee that a structs elements are stored in order (so long as the struct meets the criteria for a POD which this one does as far as I can tell).

I think it was written this way to avoid writing two different versions of QSort tailored to each struct.

My main point is that if the implementation of the structs change (the string is (re)/moved) the program will run in an unpredictable manner, and may even result in a memory violation.

Assuming the struct definition does not change. Are there any other issues with the QSort as written?

Comment: The first member of a POD (or was it aggregate...) struct is guaranteed to have the same address as the struct so that part is permanently fine.

Comment: Can you at least tell us what `MyStrCmp` and `MyString::operator*` do? And I have to ask, is `std::sort` an option?

Comment: Is `MyString` a typedef for a pointer? If not, then the double indirection in `MyStrCmp(**a, **b)` doesn't make sense to me (I suppose you'd get a compiler error as well).  Also, `std::sort()` with a functor object that performs the comparison might perform better than a sort function that takes a function pointer since there's an increased potential for the comparison to be inlined rather than being an indirect function call. You can call `std::sort()` on a plain old array - no need for it to be an STL container.

Comment: Is `MyString` a POD type that can be bitwise copied or does `appQsort()` handle copying of `myString` objects correctly? Why are you using a custom `appQsort()` instead of `qsort()`?

Comment: I'll answer the questions about MyStrCmp and MyString::operator* after i do some more digging. std::anything is not an option. It's simply a requirement of the software library that I'm using. This may sound cryptic but i'm not sure of my rights as a licensee of this software to go into more details.